# Reference static class method given class name as string in PHP5.5

Tags: php, class, static, php-5.5

I have a variable that holds a class name.

```
public $modelClass = 'common\models\Notecard';
```

That class has a static method.

```
public static function do_something() { ... }
```

Given this information, I would like to call the static function. For non-static functions, I can do the following:

```
$model_name = $this->modelClass;
$model = new $model_name();
$model->do_something_else();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is pretty easy:
You can either just call the function from your instance e.g.

```
$model_name = $this->modelClass;
$model = new $model_name();
$model::do_something();
```

or using call_user_func()

```
call_user_func([$modelClass, 'do_something']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$model_name::do_something_else()`.

```
class foo {
    public static function bar() {
        echo "Called bar";
    }
}

$fname = "foo";
$fname::bar();
```

Outputs `Called bar`

Works on php7.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am using php5.5 and this won't work. I had indicated this in the tags but not in my question itself. Will edit my question to clear this up. Thanks :)